# How to Make a HashMap Key Case Insentive?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashtable, hashcode

I have a homework about HashMaps and I'm supposed to use the following tester class, but I get a mistake in 2 lines:

for( Map.Entry entry : salaries ) and HashMap accounts = new HashMap<>(new CaseInsensitive());

I'm using eclipse btw

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;

public class Assignment {

class CaseInsensitive implements HashingFunction<String> {

   public int hashCode( String key ) {      
    return key.toLowerCase().hashCode();
   }

   public boolean equals( String lhs, String rhs ) {        
    return lhs.equalsIgnoreCase(rhs); 
   }    
}

void test1()  {

    System.out.println("Test 1:");
    HashMap<String, Double> salaries = new HashMap<>();

    // test #1a: verify that identical keys allow the same map entry to be replaced.
    salaries.put( "1000", 55000.0 );
    salaries.put( "1000", 45000.0 );
    System.out.println( "New value is " + salaries.get("1000"));

    // test #1b: add several items and display the map as a string
    salaries.put( "1234", 25000.0 );
    salaries.put( "2001", 43000.0 );
    salaries.put( "2010", 67000.0 );
    salaries.put( "2020", 37000.0 );
    salaries.put( "3010", 57000.0 );
    salaries.put( "3020", 87000.0 );

    // test #1c: test the size and toString operations
    System.out.println("\nPrinting with toString():");
    System.out.println( salaries.toString() );
    System.out.printf("Size = %d\n", salaries.size() );

    // test #1c: use the iterator
    System.out.println("\nPrinting with an iterator loop");
    for( Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : salaries ) {
        System.out.print( entry.toString() + " " );
    }
    System.out.println();
}

void test2()  {
    // test 2a: Implement a custom hashing function that ignores case differences
    System.out.println("\nTest 2:");    
    HashMap<String, Double> accounts = new HashMap<>(new CaseInsensitive());
    accounts.put( "AbCDef", 45000.0 );
    accounts.put( "abcdEF", 25000.0 );  // final value
    accounts.put( "aabCDE", 43000.0 );
    accounts.put( "AABcde", 67000.0 );  // final value
    accounts.put( "BDDEfg", 37000.0 );
    accounts.put( "bddEFG", 57000.0 );  // final value

    // Test 2b: Show that a case-insensitive insertion was used. 
    System.out.println("\n" + accounts.toString() );
    // Expected output: [AbCDef,25000.0], [aabCDE,67000.0], [BDDEfg,57000.0]

    // Test 2c: verify that the get function also ignores case differences:
    System.out.printf("\nLooking for abcdEF and AbCDef: %.2f = %.2f\n",
            accounts.get("abcdEF"), accounts.get("AbCDef"));
    // Expected output: the values are equal.
}

void test3() {
    // test 3: just making sure you created a generic HashMap class
    System.out.println("\nTest 3:");    
    HashMap<Integer, List<String>> courses = new HashMap<>();
    courses.put(1130, new LinkedList<String>());
    courses.get(1130).add( "COP 3337" );
    courses.get(1130).add( "MAD 3105" );
    courses.get(1130).add( "PHY 2048" );
    courses.get(1130).add( "CDA 3033" );

    courses.put(1131, new LinkedList<String>());
    courses.get(1131).add( "COP 3530" );
    courses.get(1131).add( "CDA 4101" );
    courses.get(1131).add( "PHY 2049" );
    courses.get(1131).add( "ENC 2301" );
    System.out.println(courses);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Assignment app = new Assignment();
    app.test1();
    app.test2();
    app.test3();    
}
```

}

Comment: What is your question? Also, why not test with `String` keys containing a mix of upper and lower case letters?

Comment: What are the errors that you're getting?

Comment: There's no JDK that I'm aware of that has a `java.util.HashMap` that takes in a constructor parameter of type `HashingFunction` (Another non-standard type). Are you sure you're supposed to be using the built-in `java.util.HashMap` and not one provided for this assignment? Perhaps it's a simple incorrect `import` problem.

Answer (score 0):

Java hashmaps do not take a "hashing function" as the argument to their constructor.

It looks like your intent is to say "hey, for this hash map, I want you to use a hashing function for the key so that its hash code is the existing hashcode for the lowercase version of the string."  But that's not how you would do it in Java.

If you want to go that route, you would have to make a class called `MyString` that wraps a string and overrides hash code as you did in your attempt.  (You *cannot* override Java's `String` because it is a final class.)

Your hashmap would then be of the form `HashMap<MyString, Double>`.  But this would invalidate the test unless you subclassed `HashMap` so that `put` and `get` took in strings.  If that is what the assignment is, I guess you have to play along.